# Do these diagnostic plots show that my best model has good fit?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, residuals

Background information: I am analyzing a dataset with about 120 unique animals that were radio-tracked  1-6 years. Most of them were radio-tracked for a year, but a handful of them (about 20) were radio-tracked for max 6 years. I used a generalized linear mixed model because the residuals were not normally distributed.

After running several models and using AIC to select the "best" model, I have the following best model:

```
  m1 = glmer(distperday ~ experience + (1|id),
           data = data, family = Gamma(link = log),
                control = glmerControl(optimizer ="optimx", optCtrl = list(method = 'nlminb')))
```

Here distperday is the average distance per day travelled by an individual.
Experience indicates how long they have spent in the wild in years.

However, when I checked the diagnostic plots for the best model, they look as follows:
[image]

Should I  be concerned about the fitted vs. resid plot? What could be causing that kind of dispersion?

Comment: Hi @Rnoobie. Non-normal (e.g. gamma) models are notoriously difficult to assess using normal QQ-plots because they aren't normal! A really good resource for this is the [`DHARMa` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) - I suggest using its simulated residuals to assess the quality of a GLMM fit.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I tried the DHARMa package but it showed me underdispersion. But my model was already simply so I wasn't sure how to proceed from there. That's why I tried these diagnostic plots instead.

Comment: I don't know what it could be. It could be a mis-specified model, e.g. if you a missing a time correlation term. If it's an animal tracking set, the distance travelled on day $i$ may be related to the distance on day $i-1$

Comment: Hmm, but subsampling is not an option for me. Perhaps transforming the response variable could help?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "subsampling"?

Comment: It involves removing some datapoints (for example, when an animal is tracked twice a day, and if no movement is detected).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about, but - if you do have a time variable available to use, I think you should at least try to put it in the model to account for day-to-day effects.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, I thought your comment was about autocorrelation of location data.

Comment: I am referring to adding an autocorrelation term (e.g. AR(1)) to the model :) for each animal